# area of 2 triangles are the same. Work out x in the form a+- square root of b

Tags: algebra-precalculus, area

There are two triangles in the diagram below, A and B.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziZx0.png)

The lengths of the sides are in centimeters. The area of triangle A is equal to the area of triangle B.Work out the value of x, giving your answer in the form a ± √b where a and b are integers

Comment: What did you try? We want to help you understand math, not solve your homework

Answer (score 0):

As I explain and answer the problem, please be sure to follow along pictorially as well. We can see that two of the sides of triangle $A$ are equal in length; they are length $x$. We can also see that there is an angle in triangle $A$ that is $30$°. As such, triangle $A$ is not an equilateral triangle, but rather an isosceles triangle, so the other two angles of triangle $A$ are $75$° each. Let us draw a line segment from the top angle of triangle $A$ to the base of the triangle such that it is perpendicular to the base. This line segment that we created divides triangle $A$ into two smaller triangles. The leftmost angle of triangle $A$ is in the new triangle that is on the left of the bisecting line segment. The sum of the angle measurements in this left triangle will be $30$° from the leftmost angle, plus $90$° from the bisecting line segment, plus some other angle measurement at the top angle that is less than the previously undivided $75$° angle that was once there. If the sum of these angles must equal $180$° because it is a triangle, then we can subtract $120$°, the sum of the two known bottom angles, from $180$° and that will be equal to the angle measurement at the top of the left triangle. That is equal to $60$°. Now, we can see that it is a $30$°-$60$°-$90$° triangle on the left. This triangle has special properties that we can use [[1](http://wumbo.net/30-60-90-triangle/)]. The triangle's height, which is the height of triangle $A$, can now be determined to be $x/2$. We can now apply the formula for the area of a triangle for triangle $A$.
$$A=\frac{1}{2}bh\implies A_A=\frac{1}{2}(x)\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{x^2}{4}$$
We know that the area of triangle $A$ is equal to that of triangle $B$. It is clearly implied that triangle $B$ is a right triangle with height $x+5$.
\begin{align}
A_A=A_B\implies\frac{x^2}{4}&=\frac{1}{2}(1)(x+5)\\&=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{5}{2}
\end{align}
Multiply both sides of the equation by $4$ and then subtract $2x+10$.
$$\frac{x^2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{5}{2}\implies x^2-2x-10=0$$
We can apply the quadratic formula with $a=1$, $b=-2$, and $c=-10$.
$$x=\frac{-(-2)\pm\sqrt{(-2)^2-4(1)(-10)}}{2(1)}=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{44}}{2}=\frac{2\pm2\sqrt{11}}{2}=1\pm\sqrt{11}$$
Clearly $1$ and $11$ are integers, so this solution is what we want, but let's verify our results first.
$$A_A=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{11}\right)\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{11}}{2}\right)=\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{11}\right)^2}{4}=\frac{2\sqrt{11}+12}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{11}+6}{2}$$
Now, the area of triangle $B$.
$$A_B=\frac{1}{2}(1)\left(1+\sqrt{11}+5\right)=\frac{\sqrt{11}+6}{2}$$
The area of the two triangles are equal for $x=1-\sqrt{11}$ as well. Thus, $x=1\pm\sqrt{11}$ centimeters is the solution to your problem.